# How to sort an array of object by a boolean property as well as an integer property and if that integer property is 0 then keep towards end?

Tags: javascript

I do have an array of objects.
ie.

```
var data = [
  { Id: "662705", Name: "New Choice 1", IsNew: false, Position: 1, IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "668191", Name: "New Choice3", IsNew: false, Position: 2, IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "0", Name: "New Choice", IsNew: true, Position: 3, IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "668192", Name: "New Choice2", IsNew: false, Position: 4, IsFiltered: false },
  { Id: "669371", Name: "New Choice", IsNew: false, Position: 5, IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "669938", Name: "Job t1", IsNew: false, Position: 6, IsFiltered: false },
  { Id: "669938", Name: "New Choice", IsNew: false, Position: 6, IsFiltered: true }
];
```

I want to remove the duplicates based on "Name" and tricky part here is, we just want to remove the object which contains duplicate names but we want to keep the older object which has "IsFiltered" property true and remove the newly added objects.

To check whether the object is newer older we are comparing an Id property.The newer Id might be 0 or greater than the older Id.
eg. older Id: 123, newer Id might be 0 or 456

**Cases to deal:**

1. Remove duplicate objects base on name.
2. Keep older one.
3. Keep which has property "IsFiltered" as true.

To deal with it I tried sorting an array and then filtering but it not working as expected.

Expected result:

```
[
  { Id: "662705", Name: "New Choice 1", IsNew: false, Position: 1, IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "668191", Name: "New Choice3", IsNew: false, Position: 2, IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "668192", Name: "New Choice2", IsNew: false, Position: 4, IsFiltered: false },
  { Id: "669371", Name: "New Choice", IsNew: false, Position: 5, IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "669938", Name: "Job t1", IsNew: false, Position: 6, IsFiltered: false }
];
```

**Code:**

```
data.sort(function compare(v1, v2) {
  if (v1.IsFiltered) {
    return 1;
  } else if (v2.IsFiltered) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (parseInt(v1.Id) === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if (parseInt(v2.Id) === 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

//Removing duplicate custom answer.
obj.Values = obj.Values.filter(function(value, index) {
  return (
    index ===
    obj.Values.findIndex(function(v2) {
      return (
        value.Name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "") ===
        v2.Name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "")
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. what if `Id` is zero and later a greater value?

Comment: I have added an expected result in question.
In short I want to sort my array by boolean property(Isfiltered) and by integer property(Id) but if that Id is zero then keep it towards the end.

Comment: why is `IsFiltered: true` in the result set? has zero a higher range than every other number?

Comment: @Dreamer in your expected result, position 3does not figure even though it is isFiltered, is it intended for it to be discarded because it has a '0' (meaning the '0' is stronger than the prop isFiltered) or is it a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the given result with filterd false values, you could reduce the array.

```js
var data = [{ Id: "662705", Name: "New Choice 1", IsNew: false, Position: 1, IsFiltered: true }, { Id: "668191", Name: "New Choice3", IsNew: false, Position: 2, IsFiltered: true }, { Id: "0", Name: "New Choice", IsNew: true, Position: 3, IsFiltered: true }, { Id: "668192", Name: "New Choice2", IsNew: false, Position: 4, IsFiltered: false }, { Id: "669371", Name: "New Choice", IsNew: false, Position: 5, IsFiltered: true }, { Id: "669938", Name: "Job t1", IsNew: false, Position: 6, IsFiltered: false }, { Id: "669938", Name: "New Choice", IsNew: false, Position: 6, IsFiltered: true }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!o.IsFiltered) return r;
        var index = r.findIndex(({ Name }) => Name === o.Name);
        if (index === -1) r.push(o);
        else if (o.Id === '0' || +r[index].Id < +o.Id) r[index] = o;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using your sort approach

```js
const data = [
  { Id: "0", Name: "a", comment: 'occurs after others a: dropped', IsFiltered: false },
  { Id: "2", Name: "a", IsFiltered: false },
  { Id: "1", Name: "a", comment: 'smallest a: kept' },
  { Id: "4", Name: "b", comment: 'kept by default', IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "0", Name: "b", comment: 'kept by default since isFiltered', IsFiltered: true },
  { Id: "3", Name: "b", comment: 'dropped even if id is the smallest', IsFiltered: false }
]

data.sort((a, b) => {
  // priority to filter
  if (a.IsFiltered != b.IsFiltered) return a.IsFiltered ? -1 : 1

  // priority to name
  if (a.Name !== b.Name) return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name)

  // default to id if everybody is equal
  if (a.Id === b.Id) return 0

  // 0 always to the end
  if (a.Id === '0') return 1
  if (b.Id === '0') return -1

  // finally the "standard" comparison
  return a.Id - b.Id
})

// Now we can simply keep the first name found
const noDupes = data.reduce(({ visited, clean }, o) => {
  if (o.IsFiltered || !visited.has(o.Name)) {
    clean.push(o)
    visited.add(o.Name)
  }
  return { visited, clean }
}, { visited: new Set(), clean: [] }).clean

console.log(noDupes) // items: 4b, 0b, 1a
```